# Redirect paths to a folder using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

It seems that it could be an easy task, but cann't find any answers to my problem.

I need a complicated redirect using htaccess.

I have pages with links to the products:

```
host/shop/cat/some_cat/product_info/some_product
```

I need them to be redirected to:

```
host/product_id/product_info/some _product
```

**Important:** `/some_cat/` folder always different, the extension of `some_product` page is php, which is already hidden with an htaccess rule.

My current htaccess rules are:

```
Options All -Indexes 

DirectorySlash Off 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.php 
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^/.]+)$ /$1.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/cart.php$ /shop/cart.php?products_id=$1 [QSA]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How do you get `product_id` from the original URL?

Comment: /product_id/ is a folder, its never changing, as well as the others, except the only folder: /some_cat/

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - you want the first URL to redirect to the second - how do you expect to populate `product_id` if it's not in the first one?

Comment: Sorry if i not got you right, but I don't need to populate the folder /product_id/, i can write my queries in simpler format for better understanding: like i have an url: host/folder1/folder2/some_changing_folder/product_name, need to redirect it to host/folder3/folder4/same_product_name.

Comment: You need to include your current code(.htaccess rules) in the question because how can anyone suggest something when we can't see what you are already doing with your rules? A suggestion could cause a conflict.

Comment: Options All -Indexes

DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.php
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^/.]+)$ /$1.php [L] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/cart.php$ /shop/cart.php?products_id=$1  [QSA]

Answer (score 0):

Done this, by using the following strings:

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products_id/(.*)$ http://example.com/product_id/prod_info/$2 [R,L]

I also renamed a destination folder /product_info/ to /prod_info/ to avoid conflicts.